# How to parse DDD file in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, driver, smartcard, digital

I have an output file with a C1B extension from a [smart card reader](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/449/acr39u-nd-pocketmate-smart-card-reader-micro-usb/) for truck drivers DDD.
The goal is to read this file and present it as a readable data for users. The thing is that there are several apps live that can do this but so far after couple days of research I still got nothing to work.
similar app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azsoftware.tachomobile&hl=en_US

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: the tacho mobile works, used HID OMNIKEY 3121 reader.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an implementation on android for parsing DDD's, your only solution is to implement the parser yourself, witch is a pretty challenging task. I happen to work on a project regarding tachocards myself, we have a library on elixir and it took several months to be developed.

Basic parsing by itself is not complicated, the complicated part is to parse the records array in a performant way.

A good starting point for you is: https://github.com/L1L1/cardpeek

Take a look at the source code where tachocard is parsed, there you can find very much information, like offsets and number of bits you need to read.